# 404 Not Found after refreshing the page using <base href="/"> on tomcat server

Tags: html, angular, angular-routing, angular16

I have to use `PathLocationStrategy` in my application. Using `HashLocationStrategy` is not possible. I have set  in my index.html file. But still when I try to refresh the page I am getting HTTP 404 Not Found. On local adding base href works fine. But when deployed to tomcat server, it's not working.

I changed by `LocationStrategy` to `PathLocationStrategy`. I expect it to work properly even on page refresh. But when page is refreshed it's giving 404 Not Found.

How can this be resolved.

Comment: Have you [made the necessary redirections](https://gist.github.com/marksduarte/010db40a362ea6ce7e251be659eb611c) ?

Comment: Your server needs to be configured to point all URLs to index.html so Angular can take over. You can't fix this in angular itself.

Comment: @Daniel technically you can, with hash strategy, but I get what you're saying